# Using .htaccess in a "positive" way

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter 2.0 application in a subfolder of our existing corporate site. I plan to add functionality to the site through this application which is in a folder named "ci."

The documentation of CodeIgniter explains .htaccess use in a "negative way" in that EVERYTHING is redirected EXCEPT exceptions. I am paranoid about doing this and "breaking" my existing site.

How would you write the .htaccess to ONLY redirect /news requests to a controller named News and /careers requests to a controller named Careers without preventing the original site from working as it does now?

I have NEVER used .htaccess before and have just "endured" the index.php out of fear of breaking the site. I did do some research before asking -- besides the CodeIgniter User Guide, I also found "The Comprehensive Guide to .htaccess" (http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml) and URL Rewriting (http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html) which were in depth but did not clarify for me what to do.

Thanks in Advance,
Jon

Comment: Did you try uri routing via routes.php instead of working on .htaccess? Please browse http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html for further more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressionengine documentation on writing out index.php shows examples of both the 'positve' and 'negative' ways you refer to.

http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Remove_index.php_From_URLs/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that what worked for expressionengine worked for CodeIgniter. I will read this now.

Comment: Not always the case, but expressionengine is using CodeIgniter also. :)

Comment: This is what I came up with after reading that article. However, the redirects are not working   

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|scripts|swf|movies|tsep|proxy|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond $2 ^(news\) 
    RewriteRule ^$ /ci/news/$2 [L]
    RewriteCond $3 ^(career\) 
    RewriteRule ^$ /ci/career/$3 [L]

Comment: Also make sure you have an appropriate AllowOverride directive set to pick up your htaccess file. you will also need RewriteEngine On in your htaccess, and also to have mod_rewrite enabled.\

Comment: I checked with our host and mod_rewrite is enabled. I added a directive and came up with the following -- but it doesn't work: `(Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L] RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|scripts|swf|movies|tsep|proxy|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] RewriteCond $2 ^(news) RewriteRule ^$ /ci/news/$2 [L] RewriteCond $3 ^(career) RewriteRule ^$ /ci/career/$3 [L]`

Comment: sorry but I also can't figure out how to write code in this box with line breaks ... the 4 spaces indent and the 2 spaces at the end of the line don't seem to work